# react, typescript, class with generator method ignored, webpack issue?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, class, webpack, generator

I have two different projects, the first one is created with  create react app + typescript, in this project I have a class to deal with tree structures that uses a generator:

```
class Nodo {
    key: string | number
    title: string
    parent: string | number | null
    [prop: string]: any;
    children?: Nodo[];

    constructor(key: number | string, title: string, parent: string | number | null, children: Nodo[] = [], data?: { [key: string]: any }) {
        this.key = key
        this.title = title
        this.parent = parent
        this.children = children
        this.data = data
    }
    get isLeaf() {
        console.log(this.children?.length)
        return this.children?.length === 0
    }

    get hasChildren() {
        return !this.isLeaf
    }
}


export class myTree {
    root: Nodo
    constructor(rootNode: Nodo) {
        this.root = rootNode
    }

    *preOrderTraversal(node = this.root): any {
        console.log("pre")
        yield node;
        if (node.children?.length) {
            for (let child of node.children) {
                yield* this.preOrderTraversal(child);
            }
        }
    }

    *postOrderTraversal(node = this.root): any {
        if (node.children?.length) {
            for (let child of node.children) {
                yield* this.postOrderTraversal(child);
            }
        }
        yield node;
    }

    insert(parentNodeKey: number | string, newNode: Nodo) {
        newNode.parent = parentNodeKey
        for (let node of this.preOrderTraversal()) {
            console.log("bucle insert")
            if (node.key === parentNodeKey) {
                node.children.push(newNode);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    remove(key: number | string) {
        let node: Nodo
        for (node of this.preOrderTraversal()) {
            const filtered = node.children?.filter(c => c.key !== key);
            if (filtered?.length !== node.children?.length) {
                node.children = filtered;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    find(key: number | string) {
        for (let node of this.preOrderTraversal()) {
            if (node.key === key) return node;
        }
        return undefined;
    }

}
```

this is working fine in this project, I can instantiate the tree and add nodes...

I have a second project that uses react, typescrip and webpack, I have copied the code from one project to another, and it is not working in the project with webpack, I can instatiate the class, create the root node, but when I try to insert a new node with the insert method, nothing occurs, it is like if it is ignoring the *preOrderTraversal, there is no errors or warnings, and the console.log inside the methods are not shown... I am absolutley lost...
Any help will be wellcome...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my tsconfig.json, target to ES6 and now it is working...
[image]

Comment: It would be better to copy and paste the text of your config for others to easily re-use